# Why state_machine's events not being triggered on model callback?

Tags: ruby, state-machine, ruby-on-rails-6

Below is my model code, gem used for state_machine functionality is 'state_machines-activerecord':

```
class Response < ApplicationRecord
  state_machine initial: :created do

    after_transition on: :fire_answered, do: [:run_metrics]

    after_transition on: :fire_review, do: [:check_review]

    event :fire_sent do
      transition from: [:created, :sent], to: :sent
    end
    event :fire_review do
      transition from: [:sent, :answered], to: :review
    end
    event :fire_answered do
      transition from: [:sent, :review, :answered], to: :answered
    end
  end

  before_save :set_appropriate_events

  def set_appropriate_events
    self.state_event = 'fire_sent' if sent_time.present? && response_time.blank?
    self.state_event = 'fire_answered' if sent_time.present? && response_time.present?
    self.state_event = 'fire_review' if needs_review?
  end
end
```

Callback runs value of 'self.state_event' is also set based on conditions, but event is not fired and no state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

To fire a event, you should use model instance to call the method.
Ex: `model_instance.event_name`

so, in your case, you may have to use like the following

```
def set_appropriate_events
    self.fire_sent if sent_time.present? && response_time.blank?
    self.fire_answered if sent_time.present? && response_time.present?
    self.fire_review if needs_review?
end
```

just call the event and it should work

Comment: BTW: I won't use array if there's only one thing to do in [after|before] transition

`after_transition on: :fire_answered, do: :run_metrics`

Comment: I get "stacklevel too deep" on solution provided by you.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure whether it can write `transition from: [:created, :sent], to: :sent`
that `from` and `to` are same event......

Comment: Yeah, machine can transition within same state.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this gem the wrong way. If you only want to update to a specific state after save then assigns the state value you want to the instance's attribute directly.

```
def set_appropriate_events
  self.state = "sent" if sent_time.present? && response_time.blank?
  self.state = "review" if sent_time.present? && response_time.present?
  self.state = "answer" if needs_review?
end
```

Notice: Above code will not trigger the `gem's callbacks` (like `after_transition`)

If you want to do a specific task and also update the state after save, DO NOT use state machine transitions, call the machine methods inside your callback method.

```
def set_appropriate_events
  if sent_time.present? && response_time.present?
    self.state = "review"
    run_metrics
  end
  ...
end
```